# For each of the numbers in the list, determine whether they are odd or even

Tags: python-3.x, list, function

Provided is a list of numbers. For each of the numbers in the list, determine whether they are odd. If the number is odd, add True to a new list called is_odd. If the number is even, then add False

```
num_lst = [3, 20, -1, 9, 10]

def odd(x):
    return x % 2 != 0


print(odd(num_lst))
```

Comment: This just asks if the entire list % 2 != 0. You might need a loop of some sort to check each element and add it to the `is_odd` list which you'll need to create. There's no real question here, so I'll leave this suggestion and let you work it out. Good luck!

Comment: You seem to have missed the *For each* in your assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with a simple for loop:

```
num_list = [3, 20, -1, 9, 10]
is_odd = []

def odd(x):
    return x % 2 != 0

for num in num_list:
    is_odd.append(odd(num))

print(is_odd)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a for loop, an if statement and the accumulation pattern with conditionals:

```
num_lst = [3, 20, -1, 9, 10]

is_odd = []                   #create an empty list

for i in num_lst:             #iterate through the sequence: "for each element (i) in num_list"

    if i%2 == 1:              # % returns the reminder after division
        is_odd += [True]      # if the reminder is equal to 1, than i is odd
    else:                     # if it is not, than i is even
        is_odd += [False]

print(is_odd)
```